# How to use a List or Data Extension to filter another Data Extension?

Tags: email, soap-api, java, fuel-sdk, filters

I have a scenario where I need to filter out (or remove) records of a Data Extension that exist in other Data Extension. In SQL would perform a NOT EXISTS.

As I need to create an external process that performs the download of Data Extension, the Suppression mechanism does not solve since this is applied only when the sending occurs.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Query Definition that uses SQL to do the comparision and writes the _CustomObjectKey of the records you would like to delete to another DataExtension.   Your external process can take the content of the resulting DataExtension and enumerate the records and delete items from the source DataExtension.  You can perform a QueryDefinition and wait for it to complete via the API ([Perform Query Definition](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/performing_a_query_activity_using_the_soap_web_service_api/)).